# Error in connecting to SQL Server Database in Node js?

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am learning how to use Node js with sql server database. I am trying to connect to a sql server database but there is this problems that I am having when I enter the server ip address in my databaseconfiguration in node js. Kindly can anyone help me to fix the error. This is the connection string that my dbadmin has given me.

```
<add name="ElmaReport" connectionString="Data Source=172.20.3.32\SQL2015;Initial Catalog=ElmaTest;User ID=realm;password=friend" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am trying to use this connection string in my node js database configuration.

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var addr = "172.10.3.22/SQL2014"; //This is where the error is.It doesn't understand the '/' character.
var config = {
    "server":addr,
    "user": "realm",
    "password": "friend",
    "database": "ElmaTest"
};

sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);


});



var updateMember = function( username, password) {
    return sql.execute( {
        procedure: "updateMember",
        params: {

            firstName: {
                type: sql.NVARCHAR,
                val: username
            },
            lastName: {
                type: sql.NVARCHAR,
                val: password
            }
        }
    } );
};

function  connecttoDb() {

  //  updateMember("elma","pass1234");
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);


    });


}

module.exports.datavalue = connecttoDb();
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems like SQL2014 is a db name. Have you tried to connect without /SQL2014 after the ip address?

Comment: @javaevgen "SQL2014" is the name of a SQL Server instance here, the database name seems to be "ElmaTest".

Answer (score 0):

From the [mssql package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) (within the examples):

> You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance

Of course you'll have to replace "localhost" with your server address and "instance" with your SQL Server instance name.